# How do I read a complete XML Element with its children while getting data from NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, async-await, c#-5.0, networkstream

The code I have until now looks like this.

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{                    
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (r.NodeType) {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (r.IsEmptyElement) // no attributes
                {
                    OnReceive("<" + r.Name + " />");
                }
                else // has attributes
                {
                    OnReceive("<" + r.Name + ">");
                    while (r.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        OnReceive(r.Name + " -> " + r.Value);
                    }
                }                                
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My XML looks like follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<start>
    <a>
        <b></b>
        <c>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
        </c>
        <e>
            <f>TEST01</f>
        </e>
        <g/>
        <h/>
    </a>
...
```

As soon as I hit the XML element `<a>` I would like to read it to the end (until I hit `</a>`) and then fire an event with the whole element and its children.

How do I do it? Is there some mechanism in place that lets me read the stream like that (wait until the end of an element) and then continues with other XML parts?

Comment: Have you looked at [ReadSubtree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/55c7aswf(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's probably doable with `ReadInnerXmlAsync`.

```
switch (r.NodeType) {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                if (r.Name.Equals("a"))
                                {
                                    string x = await r.ReadInnerXmlAsync();
                                    OnReceive(x);
                                }                               
                                break;
                        }
```

Comment: Probably? Are you saying you didn't even try it?

Comment: I did. However I encounter other problems which are described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231945/why-does-xmlreader-readinnerxmlasync-hang-when-reading-nselement. That is why I write: "probably". Now I know: This is "probably" not the way to go.