# Why does XmlReader.ReadInnerXmlAsync hang when reading <ns:element>?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, async-await, c#-5.0

I encounter strange behavior of the `XmlReader.ReadInnerXmlAsync()` method. While the following code works...

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{                    
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (r.NodeType) {                            
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (r.Name.Equals("c"))
                {
                    string x = await r.ReadInnerXmlAsync();
                    OnReceive("[ " + x + " ]");
                }                                                                
                break;                            
        }
    }
}
```

...and the whole element `<c></c>` from the following XML is read as string.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<namespace:open>
    <namespace:a>
        <b></b>
        <c>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
            <d>TEXT01</d>
        </c>
        <e>
            <f>TEST01</f>
        </e>
        <g/>
        <h/>
    </namespace:a>
...
```

I cannot read `<namespace:a>` with the same code (`r.Name.Equals("namespace:a")`). Why? The code just blocks at string `x = await r.ReadInnerXmlAsync();` and I know for sure that the data arrives in seconds.

Is it because of the fact that "If the reader is positioned on a leaf node, calling ReadInnerXml is equivalent to calling Read." (which blocks until more data is sent) which is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readinnerxml.aspx? How do I get around this?

**How do I read inner or outer XML without having to wait for more XML data?**

UPDATE:

I found one solution.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(r.ReadSubtree());
doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```

Maybe someone will provide something more elegant.

Comment: How are you calling this code? Do you use `Wait()` or `Result`?

Comment: You are missing the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(r.ReadSubtree());
doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```

Maybe someone will provide something more elegant.